# Entering Sleep state due to 'Low Power Sleep': Using AC (Charge:53%) 46 secs

Tags: iphone, battery, sleep-wake

***This question is def. not a duplicate of the ones linked. "Your Battery is Dead", I'm afraid, is not the solution.***

Edit: The event did not happen with AC plugged in, it happened on battery. I then plugged in the AC in order to wake it. The battery is fine and does not need replacement.

So I woke my MBP from sleep, plugged in my iPhone and within a minute, computer put itself back to sleep. I plugged the AC in, woke it up and checked the logs. The offending message is the title of this Q.

My battery has gone through about 926 cycles, so not exactly dead. Couldn't for the life of me figure out what had happened, but I run Micro Snitch in the background, which happened to be telling me that a microphone had kept getting connected/disconnected.

Well, at that point, I quickly realized that the Apple Lightning to USB adapter I plugged in was faulty and constantly cycling on/off, thus throwing my machine into disarray, as Photos and iTunes are set to open automatically when my phone is attached.

I'm guessing that the algorithm used to determine "remaining charge" decided that if my laptop kept doing what it was doing, the battery would very quickly die, so it put itself to sleep.

Of course, I could be wrong.

My question is, does anyone know where I can look to verify this (or what) happened, exactly? 'Low Power Sleep' isn't exactly an error, so my guess is this would be logged as an ordinary event.

Here is current battery info:

```
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   4893
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: Yes
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   7426
  Cycle Count:  926
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    3586
  Voltage (mV): 12436
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Allan I don’t think it’s a dupe. My battery is fine. I think it’s a result of my machine handling an iPhone being connected/disconnected every second. Possibly even more rapidly than say the iPhone “connected sound” can even indicate. For all I know, it could’ve been cycling 10+ times a second.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: @Allan Micro Snitch was a tell. I then confirmed by looking at the battery icon on my iPhone to verify it was toggling between charging and not.

Comment: Not that it was cycling, but that this cycling somehow caused a feedback from the USB port back into the USB controller and ultimately into the power rail that's connected to the battery which, coincidentally is protected by diodes that limit current flow in only one direction?

Comment: The event in question happened almost instantaneously upon attaching my iPhone. Not saying there was a power surge of sorts, but that plugging my iPhone in results in a number of programs automatically opening and engaging in I/O ops.  This repeated action is what I suspect caused the machine to calculate that it was low on power, thus going to sleep. I can’t confirm it, hence the question. I also suspect that I can reproduce it (not that I want to).

Comment: If what you say is the case, then it should be repeatable.  However, it's most likely that it's a mere coincidence and not cause/effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88965/discussion-between-dylan-larkin-and-allan).

Comment: What Apple USB charger are you referring to?

Comment: @user3052786 The standard issue ones that come OEM in the box. I'm wondering if one of my USB ports is going bad. I have not been able to reproduce the issue using the other USB port (I have 2, mid 2014 MBP). However, I'm also now not able to reproduce the issue in the original port, either. That is, no toggling of the charging state.

Comment: Do you mean the ac charger for your MBP? Or are you saying you have a USB charger powering your iPhone while it's plugged into your Mac somehow?

Comment: @user3052786 I was running my MBP on battery. I then plugged in my iPhone via Lightning to USB cable. That's when it went to sleep. I then plugged in the MagSafe adapter in order to wake it from Lower Power Sleep. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: The older MacBooks got progressively worse at estimating remaining battery charge for me, that might be a factor if you don't run down your battery all the way too often and it always sits at the higher percentages. Although an iPhone plugged directly into a mac's USB port can pull upwards of 2 amps, so your theory might be right, I am thinking you would need to do repeat testing  and collect more logs if you really wanted to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @user3052786 Agreed. This question is def. not a duplicate of the ones linked. "Your Battery is Dead", I'm afraid, is not the solution.